# html/php/wordpress: How to set category link as homepage?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

First I have to disclaim: I'm entirely new to Wordpress and am in the process of wrapping my head around the way it works. I've been given an assigement to take over working on a website someone else has set up with Wordpress and I'm running into some problems I was not able to resolve through research.

The website has a homepage with a link to a `category-template` (in my case the link is called "http://udkdev.skopec.de/category/projekte/") which then displays the posts of the page which are entered over the WP-dashboard. What I would like to do is simply this: I want the posts to be displayed on the homepage itself, i.e. the posts should be visible as soon as the page loads, not through clicking on the link. Below you'll find screenshots further illustrating the specific page I'm talking about as well as the code of the site's homepage and of the category-template. First, I basically tried using the category-template's code in the homepage's php-file, which did not work (it merely displayed the message "Couldn't find any articles").

I'd be grateful for anyone who can explain this to me and help me figure it out.

The Homepage (http://udkdev.skopec.de/):

[image: Homepage]

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: startseite
*/
?>

<?php the_post(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <!--<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>-->
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

After clicking on the link leading to the category (leading to http://udkdev.skopec.de/category/projekte/):

[image: Category Template]

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper-projekte">
<div class="projekte">

    <div class="button-group filters-button-group">
        <button class="active btn" id="all">alle</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-wise-201516">WiSe15/16</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-sose-15">SoSe15</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-wise-201415">WiSe14/15</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-sose-14">SoSe14</button>
        <button class="projekt-btn" id="TEST">TEST</button>
    </div>


    <?php if (is_home()) {
    query_posts("cat=-3");
    } ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('large');
            } ?>
            </a>
        <!--<div class="meta">Tags: <?php the_tags( '', ', ', '<br />' ); ?> </div>-->
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2>Couldn’t find any articles!</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<script>
var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('.projekte > .post').fadeIn(600);
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(600);
    $('.projekte > .post').not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
    </script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Having implemented Prateek Verma's answer, the initial problem is solved now. The projects/posts are being displayed right as the homepage loads. However, this causes a subsequent issue with the display of the posts when the "Projekte"-link is being clicked on. It then reloads the display of the posts but with an annoying offset which pushes the entire section containing the posts off to the left. I have posted a .gif below which shows what I'm describing. How can I avoid this? Ideally, the "Projekte"-link should already be active when the homepage loads up and of course without the offset.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the `'query_posts'` on the home page, just like this:

```
query_posts( 'cat=2' ); //Place your Category ID inside the brackets in place of 2
```

Here is the full code of `home.php`. Please find the code below:

Home.php

```
    <?php
    /*
    Template Name: startseite
    */
    ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="wrapper-projekte">
    <div class="projekte">

        <div class="button-group filters-button-group">
            <button class="active btn" id="all">alle</button>
            <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-wise-201516">WiSe15/16</button>
            <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-sose-15">SoSe15</button>
            <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-wise-201415">WiSe14/15</button>
            <button class="projekt-btn" id="category-sose-14">SoSe14</button>
            <button class="projekt-btn" id="TEST">TEST</button>
        </div>


        <?php query_posts('cat=3'); //place your Category Id in the brackets in place of 3 ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
            <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

                    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php 
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            the_post_thumbnail('large');
                        } ?>
                    </a>
                    <!--<div class="meta">Tags: <?php the_tags( '', ', ', '<br />' ); ?> </div>-->
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <h2>Couldn’t find any articles!</h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Please find the updated code of Home.php.
If it is not helpful, the i will provide you another solution.

Hope, this may be helpful to you. Thanks

Comment: Hey Prateek, thanks so much for your answer, it definitely solves my problem. However, I'm having a new issue now with the display of the projects: When I load the homepage, the projects/posts are being displayed fine, but when I click on the "Projekte"-link on the homepage, the site is being reloaded and there is an annoying offset which pushes the project-div off to the left. Can you help me out with fixing this? I have added a .gif in the original question so you can see what I mean.